# Permutation Function no repeated letters in the string

Tags: c++, string, permutation, repeat

How would one create a loop that checks if each individual char in a string has no repeating character in any iteration? Right now, I'm trying to start from a string of a given length, starting at either all A's or consecutive, sequential alphabet starting from A. For example. Length 7 is either AAAAAAA or ABCDEFG. I wanna make sure that the string has unique characters for each index of it. so if AAAAAAA was the starting string, how would I check and change it so that each char is unique?

Comment: This can easily be done using a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) with the character as the key and an occurrence counter as data.

Comment: Oh I see! I do recall something about a function where if a value is already found, then the next iteration through the new map can happen huh. 

However, for my program, I need to continually check if the string is different as I try different letter combinations one letter at a time. This is mainly for checking up the overall string combination in a dictionary. I suppose I can iterate through the map and add the keys to a string each run as well correct?